# pixelsize of string in php

Tags: php, string, size, pixel

I have the following code to calculate the with of a string in php using a specific font.

I do have to run this on 1024 strings every 5 seconds. The code I am posting is way too low, the page takes too long to load.

Is there a faster way to do this? It does not have to be perfectly accurate, it can be off by 4/5%. But it is imperative that it does not display a shorter size than expected.

I was thinking of multiplying the length of the string by the average with of a letter, but if the string has many large letters like the capital O, then the calculated string is shorter than the real string and this is forbidden. On the other hand, If i use a larger value for an average, if the string has many short letters like the lowercase "l" then the result is Beyond my 5% tollerance.

What can be done to caluclate this really quickly?

```
$box = imageTTFBbox(15,0,"./ar.ttf",$mystring); 
$width1 = abs($box[4] - $box[0]);
```

Comment: if `$mystring` is variable within the boundaries of a simple alphabet (like in western european languages) you could pre-calculate the width of each alphabetical character and just add them up when you have the full string. This could work since the font is fixed.

Comment: will that be faster? adding 20/30 numbers for about 1000 times? (including splititng the string into an array of letters..)

Comment: It could very well be. Besides, it's simple enough for you to give it a try. You might need some simple maths to get it right like adding a safety margin to each char for spacing, etc

Comment: I find it difficult to believe that you're doing 1024 completely new and unique strings every 5 seconds. Cache your results in something with LRU like Redis. You're also probably having trouble because PHP runs single-threaded and all this happens sequentially. Leverage an async task queue like RabbitMQ with [amqplib](https://packagist.org/packages/php-amqplib/php-amqplib).

Comment: @Calimero pre-computing individual characters would be an estimate, at best as it would not take [kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning) into account.

Comment: @Sammitch yup, might be good enough for 30 chars though.